# unexpected result with postgres full text search

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

I have a table of names with an additional column for the `tsvector` value of the name.  I use the following statement to populate the `tsvector` column: `SELECT to_tsvector('simple', a.name)`.
I do not understand why the following statement does not yield a `TRUE` result:
`SELECT websearch_to_tsquery('simple', 'john r. smith') @@ to_tsvector('simple', 'john smith');`.

If I do `SELECT websearch_to_tsquery('simple', 'john smith') @@ to_tsvector('simple', 'john r. smith');`, then I get a `TRUE` response.  However, this is not good for me as my table has the `tsvector` value for 'john smith' and my search parameter is 'john r. smith'.
Any reason for this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Why did you specify the 'R.' in the query if you did not want to restrict your answers to things that have it?  FTS may be powerful, but is not psychic.

Comment: jjanes: This is what my user is entering on the search. "'john r. smith".